# Helm package deployment ingress controller aks using terraform

Tags: azure-aks, nginx-ingress, terraform-provider-azure

This is the script currently following to create nginx controller for aks cluster, below is the code

```tf
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "ingress" {
  name                = "AKS-Ingress-Controller"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  allocation_method   = "Static"
}

resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress" {
  name       = "ingress-nginx"
  namespace        = var.nginx_name
  create_namespace = true
  repository  = "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx"
  chart      = "ingress-nginx"

  set {
    name  = "rbac.create"
    value = "false"
  }
  set {
    name  = "service.type"
    value = "ClusterIP"
  }
  set {
    name  = "controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy"
    value = "Local"
  }
  set {
    name  = "controller.replicaCount"
    value = "2"
  }
  set {
    name  = "controller.nodeSelector.kubernetes\\.io/os" 
    value = "linux"
  }
  set {
    name  = "defaultBackend.nodeSelector.kubernetes\\.io/os"
    value = "linux"
  }
  set {
    name = "controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector.kubernetes\\.io/os"
    value = "linux"
  }
  set {
      name= "controller.service.type"
      value= "LoadBalancer"
  } 
   set {
      name ="controller.service.loadBalancerIP"
      value= azurerm_public_ip.ingress.ip_address
  } 
  set {
      name ="controller.service.annotations.service.kubernetes\\.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group"
      value= var.resource_group_name
  } 
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong? Greatly appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.
Once the script is done, Pods are not comming up it saying CrashLoopBackOff

```
NAMESPACE                            NAME                                                              READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
aksns-eu2-siesmart-d-ngnix-ingress   ingress-nginx-controller-7fc74cf778-d8m7q                         0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   8          17m
aksns-eu2-siesmart-d-ngnix-ingress   ingress-nginx-controller-7fc74cf778-gj8rk                         0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   8          17m
```

I don't know where is the error.. Could you help me?

Comment: Hi, if you still have this issue, please share the (1) logs from the ingress controller pods and (2) the generated manifests. `helm get manifest ingress-nginx -n ingress-nginx`

Comment: thanks for help and support, issue is resolved

Comment: @ArunVijay what was the issue and how did you resolve it?